# XSLT newbie - XML import into MS Access leaves element values blank

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, element, value-of

I have been writing an (incredibly simple) XSLT to get MS Access to read this XML document that I get from another software package, and I am having trouble getting the values of the elements to transfer over. When I source the XML document and apply the XSLT transformation, it gives me 5 fields, "EventID", "DeviceID", "Officer", "Start", and "Stop", which is great. The EventID, Start, and Stop fields all source attributes from the XML document successfully, but the DeviceID and Officer elements come up blank.

Here's the source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recording-event desiredStreamState="Routine" dvr="dvr" stop-time="2016-12-22T02:28:21Z" start-time="2016-12-22T02:20:08Z" stop-tick="1996428" start-tick="1995441" reid="00:00:12:a0:27:c0-1990499">
  <info>
    <officer id="60">Foo Bar</officer>
    <dept>9bcd1176-1c45-493f-ac27-440f1e191feb</dept>
    <vehicle>VHC2-010176</vehicle>
    <protected>0</protected>
  </info>
  <video hashType="none">
    <metadata hashCode="1b569a7dcb7f0212b574e303a4eb8031" name="tick1990499-tick1990499.mtd"/>
    <streams>
      <stream stop-tick="1996428" start-tick="1995441" num="1">
        <file hashCode="0e089f550866d3c8dd6d898516fdbb33" name="tick1995441-tick1996428-video1.mp4"/>
        <file hashCode="113fd040423905529e456985b160298b" name="tick1995441-tick1996428-video1.vtt"/>
        <file hashCode="c87cbb2e85292d3a8024cf7000473736" name="tick1995441-tick1996428-video1.json"/>
      </stream>
    </streams>
  </video>
  <etl ContentsRevision="1"/>
</recording-event>
```

Here's the XSLT that I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="recording-event">
    <Info>
      <EventID><xsl:apply-templates select="@reid"/></EventID>
      <DeviceID><xsl:value-of select="vehicle"/></DeviceID>
      <Officer><xsl:value-of select="officer"/></Officer>
      <Start><xsl:apply-templates select="@start-time"/></Start>
      <Stop><xsl:apply-templates select="@stop-time"/></Stop>
    </Info>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That's it. I tried searching the question database on here, and I think it has something to do with namespaces maybe, but no luck when I messed with them.

[image: What it looks like when I import into MS Access]

I would like it to return:

```
EventID= 2:a0:27:c0-1990499
DeviceID= VHC2-010176
Officer= Foo Bar
Start= 2016-12-22T02:28:21Z
Stop= 2016-12-22T02:28:21Z
```

What it's currently giving me:

```
EventID= 2:a0:27:c0-1990499
DeviceID=
Officer=
Start= 2016-12-22T02:28:21Z
Stop= 2016-12-22T02:28:21Z
```

Comment: You have to show us the expected output and the desired output, in *XML*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paths are off for matching elements within the XML.  Office and Vehicle are both nested elements of the Info element.  Try using the following XSL and you should get values for Vehicle (DeviceID) and Officer as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="recording-event">
<Info>
  <EventID><xsl:apply-templates select="@reid"/></EventID>
  <DeviceID><xsl:value-of select="info/vehicle"/></DeviceID>
  <Officer><xsl:value-of select="info/officer"/></Officer>
  <Start><xsl:apply-templates select="@start-time"/></Start>
  <Stop><xsl:apply-templates select="@stop-time"/></Stop>
</Info>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your time!